# Should I add ID (primary key) to composite index of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am wondering whether I need to add the primary key to the composite index of a specific table.

Lets take this query for example:

```
SELECT id
FROM listings
WHERE account_id = 123 AND
      refreshed_at < '2018-01-05 09:33:15.314763' AND
      id > 123456
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1000
```

So we can see that we have 3 fields that are being queried here:

1. ID (primary key of the listings table)
2. account_id
3. refreshed_at

Up until now I had the following index:
["account_id", "refreshed_at"]

Should I add ID to the composite key to improve performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume the table is InnoDB, since it's the default storage engine.

You don't need to add the primary key to an secondary index. It's already included at the end of every index, even if you don't add it explicitly.

That said, in the query you show, it might not be able to use the index for your condition on `id`, or the ORDER BY, because you have a range condition `refreshed_at < '2018-01-05'`. Once you use a column in the index for a range condition, subsequent columns in the index don't help for searching or sorting.

You might like my presentation: [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Comment: Thanks Bill. What kind of options do I have when I use range conditions?

Comment: MySQL gives you some limited help from [index condition pushdown](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html). That should happen automatically. You'll see a note "Using index condition" in the EXPLAIN report for your query. Besides that, all you can do is increase RAM allocation to the buffer pool, in the hopes that it's faster than reading from disk.

Comment: Is this an "InnoDB" thing? Does the same logic also apply for PostgreSQL? Also, if I have a composite index with say 2 columns and the primary key would be the last column in the index, it doesn't seem beneficial to me to include it unless there will be thousands of matches for the first 2 columns and I will be trying to select using a range based on the ID. It just seems like a very unlikely scenario. Any thoughts?